# MIME::Lite::TT::HTML Perl installation problem

Tags: perl, installation, perl-module

I am trying to install MIME::Lite::TT::HTML (Perl module) and I am getting an error. I have ALL perquisites installed (I installed through CPAN), however I get this error:

```
default not defined in test_types! at ./Build line 57
CHUNZI/MIME-Lite-TT-HTML-0.04.tar.gz
./Build test -- NOT OK
```

When running `reports CHUNZI/MIME-Lite-TT-HTML-0.04.tar.gz` the output is:

```
Distribution: C/CH/CHUNZI/MIME-Lite-TT-HTML-0.04.tar.gz
CPAN: CPAN::DistnameInfo loaded ok (v0.12)
CPAN: LWP loaded ok (v5.813)
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.22)
Fetching 'http://cpantesters.perl.org/show/MIME-Lite-TT-HTML.yaml'...Could not download 'http://cpantesters.perl.org/show/MIME-Lite-TT-HTML.yaml': 500
```

cpantesters.perl.org doesn't exist, so how can I install the module?

Comment: Upgrade Module::Build to latest version and try again

Comment: To update, I just do `install Module::Build`, correct? If so, it didn't change the result.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Please consider marking an answer as accepted if it was helpful.

Comment: No, unfortunately I wasn't able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The url `http://cpantesters.perl.org/show/MIME-Lite-TT-HTML.yaml` seems to time out. I think that's the same error you got in your output.

If the url is only needed for running the tests, you might be able to [download the module gzip](http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/C/CH/CHUNZI/MIME-Lite-TT-HTML-0.04.tar.gz), untar it and run something like `perl Makefile.PL && make && sudo make install`. Of course then you don't whether the tests would have passed.

If that doesn't work: since this seems to be a trivial plain-perl module, you might be able to just [download the .pm file](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/CHUNZI/MIME-Lite-TT-HTML-0.04/lib/MIME/Lite/TT/HTML.pm) and put it somewhere in your perl include path. Remember to put inside the directory structure `MIME/Lite/TT/`.